# Curve25519xsalsa20poly1305 key derivation

Tags: encryption, asymmetric, ecc, bitcoin

I'm working on batch-encryption of files, for a small project of mine. The files are stored encrypted on a removable drive, and the keys are stored on a trustful server. For enhanced safety, I'd like to use ONE key for ONE file. Files are encrypted using NaCl/libsodium's "sealed_box" (Curve25519xsalsa20poly1305).

Each time the client adds a file to the drive, it is encrypted using a public key, generated with `fun1(masterPublicKey, seed)`. The `seed` is itself deterministically generated from a set of non-varying file attributes, and the `masterPublicKey` is, well, a public key that belongs to the client and that's reused for all files belonging to this client.

Each time the client requests decryption for a file, the `seed` is sent to the server. It then gathers the client's private key, and calls `fun2(privateKey, seed)` to get a derived private key. This key is sent to the client, which can now decrypt the file it wanted to, but NONE of the other files.

`On the server (decryption): 
[master private key] \ 
                      \   / seed from client
                       \ /
                        \ fun(privateKey, seed)
                         -> derived private key`


`On the client (encryption): 
[master public key] \ 
                     \   / getSeed(attributes)
                      \ /
                       \ fun(publicKey, seed)
                        -> derived public key`

If you're bitcoin-savvy, think BIP32 but for encryption.

How to achieve such a thing ? Is there even a way to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you storing keys on the server?

Comment: Because I assume the client is too dumb to handle his private key ;-)
Actually, the server handles authentication, and returns the key if everything is OK. But it's unsafe to have 1 key for all files, because the client could be eavesdropping and catch the private key before the decryption, so I'd like to have a dedicated key for each file.